# Setup SVN repository subfolder specific write permission

Tags: svn

I need to setup a SVN repository which the devgroup should have full privilege to read and write except for two sub folders /1 and /2.

For /1 and /2, four users should have write permission and all other users should only have read permission.

I put the following into the configuration file, but people in devgroup still have write permission in /1 and /2.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
[project:/]
@devgroup = rw

[project:/1]
@devgroup = r
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
user3 = rw
user4 = rw

[project:/2]
@devgroup = r
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
user3 = rw
user4 = rw
```

Comment: The question is if your directories 1/ and 2/ are directly under the project root directory, or you have *trunk/*, *branches/*, *tags/* or something else under to root dir? Otherwise, you're on the right track because more specific path definitions always take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **remove** permissions from a user already granted, therefore, by providing read/write access at the root of the repository to the `@devgroup` you have provided it to all sub-trees.

The way I would achieve this is by segregating your project areas into different repositories with different permissions and then using the `svn:externals` property to bundle these into the top level repo.

The `svn:externals` property can be set on any versioned directory, and its value is a multi-line table of subdirectories (relative to the versioned directory on which the property is set), optional revision flags, and fully qualified, absolute Subversion repository URLs.

```
$ svn propget svn:externals .
1             http://svn.example.com/repos/restricted-1
2             http://svn.example.com/repos/restricted-2
```

When someone checks out a working copy of the project repo , Subversion also continues to check out the items found in its externals definition.

```
$ svn checkout http://svn.example.com/repos/project
A  project
A  project/Makefile
A  project/integer.c
A  project/button.c
Checked out revision 148.

Fetching external item into 1
A  1/security.c
...
Checked out revision 14.

Fetching external item into 2
...
```

You can then place restrictions upon the two restricted repositories to prevent the `@devgroup` users from updating these, whilst still getting them when they checkout the main project repo.